# Can maven throw error in compilation instead of runtime?

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a maven project A. It has a dependent package B. B has a dependent pacakge C.

B(version 1.0) has a method:

```java
// B(version 1.0)
public class TestB {
    public static String invoke() {
        return TestC.invoke("nnn");
    }
}
```

C(version 1.0) has a method:

```java
// C(version 1.0)
public class TestC {
    public static String invoke(String name) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In project A(depends on B1.0 and C1.0), I invoke `TestB.invoke()` and it works well.

For some reason, I have to change TestC method:

C(version 1.1)

```java
// C(version 1.1)
public class TestC {
    public static String invoke(Long name) {  // params[0] changged here
        return name.toString();
    }
}
```

In this case, A depends on B(1.0) and C(1.0), B(1.0) depends on C(1.0), it still works well. But if A depends on B(1.0) and C(1.1), it will compile successfully, but throw exception when calling `TestB.invoke()`.

My question is: Is it possible to throw this error during the compilation, not the runtime?

[image]

The picture above: In project A, I open the B source class, and Intellij knows something is wrong. I guess maven can also know it and throw a compilation error during mvn compile. Then I will be awared to notice B's developer to update C.

Well maybe it's a software engineering problem. What I described above is an abstraction. The reality is: I am working on A, and someone else works on B. In my working branch, I need to update dependency C. But I don't know how many packages denpending on C need to update C, too. Guys working on B don't know they have to update C.

Comment: Given your screenshot, you already have some tool in place in your IDE that performs static code analysis. You can usually tell your IDE to consider these issues as error and it will stop the compilation. To do the same using Maven, you'll have to find the right plugin that performs the same task. I do not really know which one is a good solution. Personally I am used to rely on Eclipse for that, I do not delegate the task to Maven.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, Maven is just a build tool hence it will only through errors during the build time (not runtime).

Maybe you can add more details like pom files and the error message, if you are looking for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would have been to have a new version of C when the API changes.

Then B would use the old version of C and so A. No error but obsolete version.

Updating B's dependency of C to the latest version would give a compile error in B.

Everything solid.

Comment: Well maybe it's a software engineering problem. What I described above is an abstraction. The reality is: I am working on A, and someone else works on B. In my working branch, I need to update dependency C. But I don't know how many packages denpending on C need to update C. Guys working on B don't know they need to update C.

Comment: Maybe from 2.3 to 2.4-SNAPSHOT. One can set that snapshot versions must alway gotten from the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

By nature, exceptions are thrown during the execution of a program. So if you are looking for a general answer : you cannot. A static code analysis tool could help you, though.

If you are looking for an answer to your specific issue, there are several ways to deal with that. A precise answer would require more details as @Ikamal pointed out.

Depending on how much control you have on the different libraries, you can refactor the code in order to remove the exception (to what extent ? No clue it really depends on the code).

Dealing with the code as it is, since you already know there is an incompatibility between the library versions, you could precise which version you require / ban to ensure you have the right compatibility. Have a look at the [Maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html).

Unit testing is another way to deal with the issue. Strictly speaking, it does not help to detect errors at compile time. But it helps detecting errors during the build of the project. Hence, before the program is executed for real.

EDIT: so in the end, it seems you are looking for a Maven plugin like this one : https://github.com/openhab/static-code-analysis/blob/master/docs/maven-plugin.md

Comment: `A static code analysis tool could help you` what is this tool? I updated my question. Intellij would know the 'B' package I dependent has something wrong, but it won't stop me to startup 'A'. I guess static code analysis tool only checks 'A' source files, not its dependencies.

Comment: For a start, have a look here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java